# Channel control on VLC TV streaming

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, vlc

I tried to stream a TV digital Channel with VLC on HTTP adress but I don't know how to chose the channel?

I can see Channels list On **>>Playback>>Programs** (there are 34 channel here) But I want to chose a specific channel to stream.

every turn I restart the streaming, VLC strat to stream a random channel.

I didn't do any special setting yet: **Capture mode: TV Digital / Tuner card: 0 / Delivery system: DVB-T / Transponder/Multiplex frequency: 578000kHz / Bandwidth: Automatic**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using VLC command line interface.

```
cvlc YOUR_INPUT_PUT_HERE --sout '#duplicate{dst=udp{dst=...},select="program=XX"}'
```

Where dst=udp{dst= is place to put your output configuration(udp,http, whatever) and XX is the program number of the program you want to stream.

Comment: Really appreciated but how can I find channel number?

Comment: if you open VLC, there is Playback -> Program menu. You should see all available Program numbers

Comment: I'm sorry Bro but I'm really noob! It's my input code >>    dvb-t://frequency=626000000      and it's my output setting   >>        :sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp1v,vb=800,scale=0.25,scodec=none}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/} :no-sout-all :sout-keep       by the way when I open Programs I have a list like this (in order) : iFILM [IRIB],OFOGH [IRIB],VARZESH [IRIB], ... so the number of channel is something like 01 or 1 or 001 ? So what is the final code?  Thanks